# Client and server communication in c for linux operating system

Tags: c, linux, sockets, operating-system, client-server

1. Client will be sending the data to server
2. server is recieving the data from the client
3. server is sending a response back to the client

and

1. client is a tool used in my project (So i dont have to code anything)
2. I already coded udp communication to send and recieve the data between client and   server (2 and 3).

I am using udp for communication between client and server

whenever we recieve the data (data is commands here) from the client -  a new OS task must be created in the server (I created three task of 2ms, 10ms and 100ms). This
task must call the API `Xcp_CmdProcessor()` to allow the server to process 
commands(data) from the client-10ms for the default
configuration. during processing the commands, it should not interrupt the other functions like recieving the data or sending the data.

how to link the operating system task created with the recieved data from the client ??

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer that if i understood it correctly.

you can create seperate `command processing threads` for each client request that you get along with some `client` specific data to identify the client later when the thread is done processing. you can look at [POSIX](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) thread programming tutorials.

Comment: An independent task creation, so that your main thread keeps listening for new client requests, can only be achieved using 2 ways: either spawn off a `process` for each new request or otherwise create a separate `thread`. maintaining & creating `thread` involves less overhead and is more efficient.